# filesystem conversion from fat32 to ntfs on external hard drive

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive, filesystems, ntfs

i'm currently having problems with a filesystem conversion on a 1TB external usb hard drive.
The drive is filled with about 300GB and attached to a windows 7 system.

The conversion was started using the windows console command "convert G: /FS:NTFS".  The process started successfully with a chkdsk and calculated the needed amount of space.  Since then nothing changed. The cursor is blinking and i cant see any progress for the last 7 days. Since there was no verbose-Switch used, i just have no clue how to recognize the current status of the process.
In taskmanager the process uses just a little amount of cpu-time and has allocated about 70MB of RAM (number is slowly increasing). I can also see that the process has read about 250GB of data (no change for days).
There is only one value in taskmanager that changes and that is the "I/O Other"-Value. This number is increasing by about 850 per second and is at a count of about 550 million operations.

I previously just converted smaller drives, but these conversions were way faster und without problems.

Now my questions:

1. Should i keep the process running and how much time should i estimate for completion?
2. Can i use the I/O Other Value in any way as a progress indicator?
3. Do you see any possibilites to rescue the data of the hard drive in case of aborting the process or if it fails?

thanks in advance

Comment: I'm guessing you did this with no backup? Pull the plug at any time now; you are already into recovery methods.

Comment: Problem is you are not supposed to be able to format a drive that large to fat32, (32gig limit) you must have used a 3rd party utility to do it, might be why the conversion process has hung.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I can also see that the process has read about 250GB of data 
>   (no change for days).

It it has not read more data for days that it is hung. Reboot (to get to a known clean state), wipe the disk and reformat it with NTFS. Then restore the data from your backup.

Comment: seems like it really hung up in the first step while reading the data. i canceled the process with ctrl+c and could access the hard drive immediately. the conversion itself hadnt even started. now reformat and restore will be the best way to change the filesystem.